# Swing + SWT Visual Editor compatible with Eclipses windowbuilder pro for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm currently studying Computer Science, and we've gotten to the point that I just got feed up with the Eclipse IDE, so I tried to make the switch to the IntelliJ IDEA, just to try it out.

The only thing keeping me from switching, is the Window Builder in Eclipse which writes the code into the class and then parses it when executing.

I know theres a feature in IntelliJ which is named GUI Builder. However the issue is that while the rest of my group along with the teachers use Eclipse's Window Builder, I still can't make a complete switch, because I can't find a way to use the GUI Builder in IntelliJ IDEA to work with hard coded (or as close as it's going to get) UI Design.

So the question at hand: How can I still edit files which is compatible with both IntelliJ's GUI Builder and Eclipse's Window Builder?

Since IntelliJ claims to use Swing + SWT, I don't see why it's this difficult to edit (both visually and in class) compared to eclipses windowbuilder.